# Swift receiving push notifications (Parse) when the app is not running

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, notifications, push-notification

I am building an iOS app using Swift and I want to receive push notifications (Parse) when someone has mentioned me.

I have used a navigation controller as the initial view controller and first view controller is the sign in view controller. In this view controller there is an if statement which checks whether the user in already logged in or not. If the user is already logged in then the app jumps automatically to the main screen.

If the sign in is successful, the app jumps to main screen.

My notifications work fine in the following cases:

- The app is running
- The app is running on the background, and when I tap on the notification bar, the app jumps on the notification screen

My notifications do not work in the following cases:

- The app is running on the background, when I tap the icon with the badge (i.e. 1) it shows the main screen and not the notification screen
- The app is not running at all, and I am running it through the notification. In this case the app is stacked on the sign in screen and it is not responding. I think that the problem is because it waits for the user to be signed in.

I do not know whether there is an issue in the AppDelegate.swift file. I have followed the Parse documentation as well as the Starter project for Parse in order to code it.

Following are the methods from the `AppDelegate.swift`

Method `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    if let notificationPayload = launchOptions? [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as? NSDictionary {
        let meetingId = notificationPayload["meetingId"] as? String
        let targetMeeting = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Meeting", objectId: meetingId)
        targetMeeting.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let meetingToRespond = Meeting(id: targetMeeting.objectId!, name: targetMeeting["name"] as! String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((targetMeeting["location"]?.latitude)!, (targetMeeting["location"]?.longitude)!), day: targetMeeting["dayTime"] as! NSDate)
                var rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let notificationScreen = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("screenForNotification") as! MeetingToRespondViewController
                notificationScreen.meeting = meetingToRespond
                rootViewController.pushViewController(notificationScreen, animated: true)
            }
        })  
    }
    // Enable storing and querying data from Local Datastore. 
    // Remove this line if you don't want to use Local Datastore features or want to use cachePolicy.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId("@@@",
        clientKey: "@@@")

    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFUser.enableAutomaticUser()

    let defaultACL = PFACL();

    // If you would like all objects to be private by default, remove this line.
    defaultACL.setPublicReadAccess(true)

    PFACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, withAccessForCurrentUser:true)

    if application.applicationState != UIApplicationState.Background {

        // Track an app open here if we launch with a push, unless
        // "content_available" was used to trigger a background push (introduced in iOS 7).
        // In that case, we skip tracking here to avoid double counting the app-open.         
        let oldPushHandlerOnly = !self.respondsToSelector(Selector("application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:")) 
        let noPushPayload: AnyObject? = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey]
        if oldPushHandlerOnly || noPushPayload != nil {   
            PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)    
        } 
    }
    if application.respondsToSelector("registerUserNotificationSettings:") {
        let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil) 
        application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
    } else {
        let types: UIRemoteNotificationType = [UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound]
        application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(types)
    }
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}
```

Method `application: didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {
    let installation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    installation.setDeviceTokenFromData(deviceToken)
    installation.saveInBackground()  
}
```

Method `application: didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
    if application.applicationState == .Inactive {   
        // The application was just brought from the background to the foreground, so we consider the app as having been "opened by a push notification."
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
}
```

Method `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler`

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    if application.applicationState == .Inactive {
        PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithRemoteNotificationPayload(userInfo)
    }
    if let meetingId: String = userInfo["meetingId"] as? String {
        let targetMeeting = PFObject(withoutDataWithClassName: "Meeting", objectId: meetingId)
        targetMeeting.fetchIfNeededInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object, error) -> Void in 
            // Show meeting to respond view controller
            if error != nil {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.Failed)
            } else if PFUser.currentUser() != nil {
                // Get the meeting
                let meetingToRespond = Meeting(id: targetMeeting.objectId!, name: targetMeeting["name"] as! String, location: CLLocationCoordinate2DMake((targetMeeting["location"]?.latitude)!, (targetMeeting["location"]?.longitude)!), day: targetMeeting["dayTime"] as! NSDate)
                var rootViewController = self.window?.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
                let mainStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let notificationScreen = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("screenForNotification") as! MeetingToRespondViewController
                notificationScreen.meeting = meetingToRespond
                rootViewController.pushViewController(notificationScreen, animated: true)
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData) 
            } else {
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
            } 
        })
    }
    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData)
}
```

Method `applicationDidBecomeActive: application`

```
func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Clear the badge
    let currentInstallation = PFInstallation.currentInstallation()
    if currentInstallation.badge != 0 {
        currentInstallation.badge = 0
        currentInstallation.saveEventually()
    }
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}
```

Thank you in advance!!! :D :) ;)

Comment: Have you found solution yet ?

Comment: @Ben I managed to do it in a different way.